# How to disable NSView NSViewDidUpdateTrackingAreasNotification notifications?

Tags: cocoa, nsview

I have a lot of nested NSViews and these notifications are really slowing down the application.

NSView has these methods for controlling notifications:

- setPostsFrameChangedNotifications:
- postsFrameChangedNotifications
- setPostsBoundsChangedNotifications:
- postsBoundsChangedNotifications

However, I see nothing about controlling NSViewDidUpdateTrackingAreasNotification. Does anyone know how this might be done?

Answer (score 0):

This workaround worked for me. Not recommended to override internal methods though.

```
- (void)_updateTrackingAreas 
{
    //NSLog(@"currentEvent: %@", [NSApp currentEvent].description);

    // Is it currently visible?
    if (NSEqualRects(self.visibleRect, NSZeroRect)) { 
         // No, don't update its tracking area.
        return;
    }

    [super _updateTrackingAreas];
}
```